# Long string makes other data shift to the right

Tags: java, string, formatting

I have a little formatting issue.

So basically, I'm just using databases in Java, Inserting data, Updating data, so on, just messing around. I've come accross this really annoying formatting error with my output.

```
ID   FIRST_NAME      LAST_NAME   CONTACT_NO      AGE
-------------------------------------------------------------
1   daniel      vyres       11      10
2   duck        howser      21      54
3   daniel      asdfa       11      10
4   jayy        alko        15      25
5   asdfasd     asdjajggg       15      20
6   alp     alko            15      25
7   alp     alko            15      25
```

As you can see for ID: 5
The string is longer, making all the other data shift to the right.

Here is my current formatting method:

```
System.out.println(id + "\t" + firstName + "\t\t" + lastName + "\t\t" + contactNo + "\t\t" + age);
```

If anybody could help me out with this issue, then it would be greatly appreciated.

- Thanks

EDIT: I know in the output I provided above everything looks off, but in reality all the other columns are correct (there is data directly under each field)

Comment: You should use `System.out.printf` and string format operators instead of tabs. Take a look at this: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/lang/string/java-string-format-example/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **println** it would be much easier to use **printf**.

**Sample:**

```
System.out.printf("%2d\t%20s\t%20s\t%3d\t%3d\n",id, firstName, lastName,contactNo,age);
```

You specify the datatype with a percent sign and following character.
Between these two you can specify the width, the precision and other things.

Look here for more details:
[printf Format References](http://alvinalexander.com/programming/printf-format-cheat-sheet)

Comment: Could you help me further with this? I tried something like

`System.out.printf("%-3s %15s %n", id, firstName, lastName, contactNo, age);`

However, it only printed out the first 2 columns?

EDIT: Nevermind, I understood where I went wrong, and I have the code working now, thanks allot!

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.printf("%-3s %13s %15s %13s %12s %n", id, firstName, lastName, contactNo, age);
```

Comment: It's OK answering your own question, but please consider explaining what was the cause of the problem and how/why this answers solves it.